# How to add data into datagridview combobox

Tags: c#

I have been doing this schedule system and I want to populate data inside this datagrid view where my users can select a particular value I previously saved in database and display it here to arrange data and then print...

so far I was unable to populate data inside the database. Can you guys give me a code to do this

this is my form
[image]

this is my database

[image]

Comment: What did you try already? Also, can you provide an example of application?

Comment: i tried the entity datasource binding method and its like a gym schedule arrangement system..its a custom requirment from client..i cant think of an example

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `DataSource`. Please check the link [Steps To Add Combobox Inside Datagridview](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/steps-to-add-combobox-inside-datagridview-window-form) or code below.

```
private void dgv_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex > -1)
            {
                DataGridViewComboBoxCell l_objGridDropbox = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

                if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Contains("Info"))
                {
                    dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] = l_objGridDropbox;
                    l_objGridDropbox.DataSource = GetMyData();
                    l_objGridDropbox.ValueMember = "Info";
                    l_objGridDropbox.DisplayMember = "Info";
                }
            }
        }

        private DataTable GetMyData()
        {
            DataTable lInfo = new DataTable();
            lInfo.Columns.Add("Info", typeof(string));

            lInfo.Rows.Add("A");
            lInfo.Rows.Add("B");
            lInfo.Rows.Add("C");


            return lInfo ;
        }
```

Comment: Ok appreciate that. Best wishes. :)